# OT_TIMEOUT Session.publish :: Could not publish in a reasonable amount of time

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

```
../node_modules/@opentok/client/dist/js/opentok.js:17105:66 . onPublishingTimeout
```

Getting OT_TIMEOUT happened in Win 8, Chrome 79.0.3945.

How to catch/handle this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manik here from the OpenTok Team.

You can catch these exceptions by setting an event listener on the `OT` object like so:

```
OT.on('exception', (error) => {
 // handle exception
});
```

For more information, please take a look at the [ExceptionEvent](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ExceptionEvent.html) documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to know why this happens?, because catching exception could be fine but its stopping the webrtc functionality itself and that too OpenTok supported browsers itself .

Comment: Failure to publish can be due to a few reasons such as the media unable to connect to the other peer whether that's routed or relayed. I would recommend filing a support ticket and sharing the sessionId so they can help debug.

Comment: I filed and didnt get specific response for this and more over this exception doesnt come to mentioned code

Comment: developing a POC atm and this error has caused me to down tools. Is it possible to get an answer or fix to this issue?